# Flow through pipe while being lifted from water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, flow, lift

The setting is as follows. A hollow pipe (flooded) with radius R-pipe is being lifted from below the water surface (totally submerged) to above the water surface with a speed of v1. The pipe is closed at the top and the bottom. The crane that is lifting the pipe does not want to lift the water that is inside the pipe as well. What size holes (how many) do you have to drill at the top of the pipe and the bottom of the pipe so natural flow through the pipe occurs (if this even does occur)?

[image]

Also, when the pipe is being lifted from the water (so while a part is still in the water) you don't want the water level in the pipe to be higher than the level of the water surface (you don't want to lift the extra kilo's). I thought this was the case:

[image]

But I think there is something wrong. So how big should the hole at the top and bottom be related to the lift speed and the height between the two holes so water flows through the pipe? Does water even flow through when the holes are in the side of the pipe?

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. What does "so natural flow through the pipe occurs" mean? Natural flow occurs when the pipe has no top or bottom at all, and does not restrict the free movement of water. Any top or bottom will affect *natural flow* to some extent.

Comment: @sammygerbil: I disagree somewhat. It could have been formulated better but it's quite clear what the question means.

Answer (score 1):

> Does water even flow through when the holes are in the side of the
>   pipe?

Only if the surface of the water in the pipe is *higher* than the surface of the water in the reservoir. And this is precisely what you don't want:

> Also, when the pipe is being lifted from the water (so while a part is
>   still in the water) you don't want the water level in the pipe to be
>   higher than the level of the water surface (you don't want to lift the
>   extra kilos).

As long as the water levels are the same, *no flow occurs* because the [hydrostatic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law) on both sides of the submerged holes is exactly the same. Bernoulli then tells us no flow will occur.

So in order for flow to occur from the pipe into the reservoir, the levels in pipe and reservoir **must effectively be different**, violating your condition.

Comment: That's true, but a tiny difference in water levels would have contributed to a flow while barely increasing the load. Hope op would clarify further, as tiny difference wouldn't matter in real life situations but mean the world in homework assignments.